# Python datetime comparison is incorrect in case of compare two time like: 12:00 and 11:59

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-comparison

so below example of code:

```
 >>> from datetime import datetime
 >>> future = datetime.strptime('12:00', '%I:%M')
 >>> past = datetime.strptime('11:59', '%I:%M')
 >>> future < past 
 >>> True # expected False, because '12:00' > '11:59'
 >>> past_2 = datetime.strptime('11:58', '%I:%M')
 >>> past < past_2
 >>> False
```

why datetime compare operation returns *True* instead of *False*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%I` is the hours for a twelve hour clock. Unless you supply an AM or PM (`%p`), it takes the AM choice. 12:00 AM (i.e. midnight) is before 11:59 AM.

If you use `%H` you get 24 hour clock, in which 12:00 will be noon instead of midnight.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Thank you a lot, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

strptime in this case maps '12:00' to midnight ... the format specifier %I "means": "Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number."

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is *which* `12:00` you mean. Printing out the datetimes in question might help you to understand:

```
future, past, past_2
```

has the value:

```
(datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 59),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 11, 58))
```

As you can see, 12:00 is interpreted as being at the *start* of the day, while `11:59` is interpreted as almost midday, 11 hours and 59 minutes later.